# Objective-C: how to add a new cell for each filename in UiTableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Bellow i have some code that lists the path to the documents directory where my video files are saved. The code then lists that in a cell but it's the full path and only one cell is used. So what i want to do is first cut down the path and only list the file name of the file in the documents director and then have an individual cell for each file. Is that possible?

**Here is the code i am using to list the path to the documents directory:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];


}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(!filePathsArray)  // if data loading has been completed, return the number of rows ELSE return 1
    {

        if ([filePathsArray count] > 0)
            return [filePathsArray count];
        else
            return 1;
    }

    return 1;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible, however you should store each element of the path in an `NSArray` instance variable **once** and then access this `NSArray` to provide the row count and row content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is now, you're loading the file paths in `viewDidLoad` **and** each time the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called which is inefficient and unnecessary.

In any case, you just want something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
```

if I understand your requirements correctly.

Comment: that is working great thanks but how can i now list multiple files in different cells

Comment: You mean one file per cell, but more than one cell in the table?

Comment: I mean one file per cell. So have multiple cells in one table

Comment: @Macro206 Yes thats what i mean

Comment: If your implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is correct, you would have have one row per file.  That method just needs to return `[filePathsArray count]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
NSFileManager *fm [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *documentsDirectoryContents = [[fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

It works for me, and only returns the filenames of the files within the documents directory (not the full path).
Then use that array as your data source for the table.
So set each cell's text to the corresponding file name.

Furthermore, as NSBum says, you should obtain the filenames ONLY when you want the documents directory's contents to be refreshed - in other words, only when you want to update your table.